# Source maps with browserify, typescript and gulp

Tags: typescript, gulp, browserify, source-maps

I have some typescript code. What I want is:

```
.ts files -> tsc -> .js files -> browserify -> single .js file
```

I can do this but I have a problem with source maps. When I launch the browser the path to .ts files is incorrect (`source/`). I don't know where to set it. I've already seen many sites but I can't use any of given solutions (high chance I do something wrong).

To get what I have right now I use:

```
gulp tsc && cd temp && browserify --debug Application.js > app.js
```

I have following `gulpfile.js`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'); 
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

gulp.task('tsc', function() {
    return gulp
      .src("src/*.ts")
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
         .pipe(ts({
              target: "es5"
              , module: "commonjs"
          }))
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
      .pipe(gulp.dest("temp"));
});
```

I don't use gulp-browserify as it is no longer maintained as stated [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-browserify). I couldn't find what is best method to do this currently.

**Update**

I managed to do it with:

`browserify src/Application.ts -p [ tsify --target=es5 --module=commonjs ]  --d
ebug > temp/app.js`

However I am interested in using gulp to solve this problem.

**Update**

I found a solution on the typescript site [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/gulp.html). My gulp task is:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    browserify = require("browserify"),
    source = require('vinyl-source-stream'),
    tsify = require("tsify");

var tsconfig = {
    noImplicitAny: true,
    target: "es5",
    module: "commonjs"
};

gulp.task("default", function () {
    return browserify({
        basedir: ".",
        debug: true,
        entries: ["src/Application.ts"],
        cache: {},
        packageCache: {}    
    })
    .plugin(tsify, tsconfig)
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("js"));
});
```